# 74181 in odd carry logic in active high mode

Tags: alu, 74ls181

Out of the popular but closed question [74'181 ALU why would anyone (have) use(d) these wild functions?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/74181-alu-why-would-anyone-have-used-these-wild-functions) I break out one part. I don't get the carry logic.

Normally your addition works by giving A + B with carry-in being low, and A + B + 1 with carry-in being high.

The 74181 gives A + B - 1 when carry is low, and you need to hold carry high to get A + B. I don't understand why that is.

Supposedly you should be able to just ripple carry through (I know /P and /G do the fast-carry thing for wider words, but you can still ripple carry if you just have 8 bit words) so I guess the active low on the carry-out combines with that.

But I find it super confusing. Compare that with the 74283 fast adder, where the carry logic is "normal" A + B + carry, active high carry in and out.

What am I not getting about this carry logic?

Comment: Dumb question. For searchabilty should this be "74'181" or 74181" in the title? The only hits I get in google are for a related StackExchange question: [74'181 ALU why would anyone (have) use(d) these wild functions?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/74181-alu-why-would-anyone-have-used-these-wild-functions)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome the other question you linked is mine too. I have made a tag 74ls181. I think people tend to see some letters between 74 and 181, that's why I put the apostrophe. But searches for 78181 find all of them.

Comment: So long as they're searchable, I'm just not used to seeing the part numbers written in that fashion.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I used the 74181 in my own CPU in 1974. (Several of them, actually.) I didn't use all the functionality. But there is a great deal of method to what you imagine as madness. And at the time, I never once felt any quandary. I just used what I needed. But there is a [good page](https://www.righto.com/2017/03/inside-vintage-74181-alu-chip-how-it.html) to read that may help you in your struggles. Keep in mind, also, that at the time it wasn't difficult to provide all permutations of an idea and allow the designers to work out which are useful.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Given time and experience and a modern 20/20 hindsight we may better say today that certain specific permutations aren't often found anywhere in practice and ask "why?" But at the time, CPUs were under very active research and investigation and if there were logical permutations available, why not support them and allow those doing the work to figure out which matter to them more? Everything made complete sense to me then. It was machine providing all logical permutations. And that made sense to me, then. Still does, actually.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Also, and this isn't a comment specific to the 74181 but more generally, the NPN BJT was the workhorse. Open collector was provided along with 2-quadrant drive in equal share (only a slight preference was made, one to another.) Wire-or/and was commonly used and 'active' was often considered LO because there was more drive capability from the low quadrant BJT in the 2-quadrant output driver. Basically, you could drive an LED from a LO output. But not a HI. So there are cases where you wonder why the outputs are the opposite of the inputs. (7489.) That is why.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR:

It seems as if you're mixing up high level interpretation with circuit representation and signal level. Carry input is a low active signal, noted by the bar above. A 'Low Level' at carry means 'Set' in this system.

---

Some clarifications about the areas and terms involved:

### Numbers, States and Levels

While we tend to use (and assume) the

- numeric values of '0 and '1' (*1), the
- control states 'Active' and 'Inactive' and the
- signal levels of 'Low' and 'High' (*2)

interchangeable in every day talk, they are not. They describe three different concepts and are used in three different ways. In a school book world they even may be always the same - in the real world one has to be cautious to keep them apart an know exactly when to use which, or when the context allows rather generic use.

#### Numeric Values

Numeric values are digits, usually binary. They they have no preferred 'Active' state. But to be handled in hardware, they need to be represented, which is done by mapping 'Signal Levels' (*3). Doing so is called 'Active High Data' when a 'High' level is assigned to the digit of '1' (and 'Low' to '0'), the other way around it'll be 'Active Low Data'.

#### Control States

States are signals representing some ... well, state :)) In most cases states carry only two flavours, present or not (*4). In Logic they are called 'True' or 'False'. Same usually in Programming. In electronics states are described as 'Active' and 'Not Active' or 'Inactive'.

To make it work, they again have to be have to be mapped onto 'Signal Levels'. If the true/active state is represented by a 'High' level that signal is called 'High Active', otherwise it's 'Low Active'. Usually one mentions this only for low active signals

In schematics this is usually marked by an inversion bar above the name. When used in text a leading slash in front of the name may be used as well (*5).

Also important, these are not values, aka 'Data'. So 'Low Active States' and 'Low Active Data' are two different items, only related by the way their meaning is mapped onto 'Signal Levels'

#### Signal Levels

The next step are 'Levels'. They are how 'Values' and 'States' are mapped onto real hardware with their wires and voltages. To map binary signals (*6) onto electric signals, usually a voltage difference of Zero and non-Zero is used, with Zero being called 'Low' and non-Zero called 'High'.

In most cases non-Zero is a positive voltage, for TTL-alike circuitry commonly close to 5 Volt.

### Don't Mix It Up

Looking at above shows that there are different domains to talk about and each fosters their own specific language. Languages that seem close and overlapping, but not the same. Thus one can not transfer meaning on one domain (like programming or logic) to any other (like hardware) without being very clear what it is about. **Likewise language from one level can not be used to describe any other**.

Or in case when reading of an active low signal (like /C) in a circuit description will not mean that a 'Low' is a '0' as in 'Not Set', like in programming, but quite the opposite, it's a '1' as in 'Set'.

**Long Story Short:**

Programming language is to electronic language like American English to British English. It may look quite the same until the moment you meet a chippy. Only the Mancunian chippy (*7) will ask about cheese and vinegar.

---

Now back to

### The Question

> The 74181 gives A + B - 1 when carry is low, and you need to hold carry high to get A + B. I don't understand why that is.

Could it be that you're looking at the wrong table? In my data sheet a selection of LLLH with 'Active High Data' (as stated in the questions title) gives A+B+Carry.

[image: Table#2 from '181 datasheet]

Carry is defined as a 'Low Active' signal. that means a voltage at (close to) 0V is 'Active' or what one may call a logic '1'.

Of course, if you've been looking at table#1, then you've looked at 'Active Low Data' - which utilizes an 'Active High' carry - but then one need to read the results accordingly as 'Active Low Data', where HHHL which in 'Active High Data' would be minus one is a straight one.

Supposedly you should be able to just ripple carry through (I know /P and /G do the fast-carry thing for wider words, but you can still ripple carry if you just have 8 bit words) so I guess the active low on the carry-out combines with that.

> But I find it super confusing. Compare that with the 74283 fast adder, where the carry logic is "normal" A + B + carry, active high carry in and out.

Which is exactly what the '181 does at well. Adding (with carry) is done as A+B+Carry. Remember, Carry is, when using 'Active High Data', defined as 'Active Low' as shown in the assignment table:

[image: Pin assignment depending on Active High Data or Active Low Data usage]

A 'Low' on /Carry does mean 'Carry Set'.

And that's exactly the same behaviour as with a '283, where a 'High' notes a 'Set' carry. All well described in the signal description (*8)

> What am I not getting about this carry logic?

Maybe the point that carry is not a Value but a State, a state encoded according to definition?

---

As a conclusion the maybe an underlaying question might be added:

> Why is the carry definedas 'Low Active'?

*(In fact this might be some what implied by comparison to the 'High Active' definition used by the '283)*

They may have included many notable considerations:

1. It doesn't matter for function - logic doesn't care for using 'Low' or 'High' to mark the 'Active' state.
2. It saves circuits (two inverting gates) - quite important for a chip that complex for its time
3. It speeds up execution - making it 'Active High' would need two inverter stages, at least one of them along the timing critical ripple carry path.
4. When used in a CPU, carry comes either

   - from a [flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)), which usually will provide either variant in parallel (as Q and /Q), or
   - from some control logic, which more often than not will as well prefer 'Low Active' outputs, as ...

... TTL designers **love** 'Low Active' states. Just look at all select signals you may find with memory or device decoding, request signals, or enable signals. They are more often 'Low Active' than 'High Active'.

There is a whole series of reasons to do so, from simpler gate design to higher output current to faster switching and more. Going into that would be rather an EE question than RC.SE related, wouldn't it?

---

*1 - I will use single quotation marks and uppercase spelling thruout this answer to mark certain exact terms, to avoid them getting get mixed up with less exact common language use.

*2 - Or better 'High Voltage Level' and 'Low Voltage Level' as that's what these mean.

*3 - In every day hardware handling often called 'Logic Levels' to mark the difference from analogue levels - which they cover a range of.

*4 - Of course there may be states with multiple - like the S4..S0 select signals of a '181, used to select the function to be performed.

*5 - A convention useful at a time when most non cursive documentation was primary done by typewriter. It got enforced with early EDA systems and their need to stay within existing codesets without additional markup.

*6 - Non-binary states may of course need [more than two representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer) which can be various voltage levels and/or polarity. But that's a story forgotten by today's digital technology ... or not when looking at [MLC storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell).

*7 - His drugs are beer battered fish and fine potato sticks - no [trams](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tram#Etymology_1) either.

*8 - Also noteworthy, the '283 does not work with either data representation, but only with 'Active High Data' - which of course simplifies description a lot.