# 74'181 missing zero flag but strange -1 (or all 1) flag, only makes sense in active-low mode?

Tags: alu, 74ls181

Out of the popular but closed question [74'181 ALU why would anyone (have) use(d) these wild functions?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/74181-alu-why-would-anyone-have-used-these-wild-functions) I break out one aspect, that of a missing zero flag output.

If I wanted to build a CPU with the typical flags Zero, Negative and oVerflow, I have the unconfirmed *feeling* that I could use /G and /P and /F3 to emulate N and V, but I don't see how I can get a Z flag bit without adding the usual 4 or 5-input NOR gate.

What did real world '181 CPUs do to get a Z flag? The A=B open-collector bit that comes out on pin 14 is active when F0-F3 are all one. So it seems like in active low mode this would make sense.

Was the 74'181 really intended to be used in active low mode then? Did the actual machines that used it somehow ran the ALU core in active low and used registers and bus transceivers or memory that were also inverting or active low? It seems so strange!

Comment: I used an 8-bit NOR to get it in 1974 when I was using those. If you find a nicer way, let me know. Regarding the A=B that was done to make it easy to wire-or. At the time, as I already said, open collector was quite common. Almost just as common as 2-quadrant drive. (Seemed so at the time. I've not done a quantitative comparison from their 1972 databook I was using.) But when there was a pin that was just begging for wire-or? That's what they arranged. This was one such case.

Comment: If this is a question in its own right, then please remove the reference to that other question, if not, then it might be rather confusing to add it.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR:

An ALU operates on its inputs, not its output. **Testing a result** for zero **is not an ALU operation**, nor is it a direct (by-)product, like carry.

The '181 is a basic ALU not the final ALU- block for a specific CPU. It's meant to deliver operations on one or two input operands (plus carry), not to interpret them.

A=B is part of the result when used in comperator mode (where F0..4 is of no use), not a test about the result on its own(*1).

Of course the additional function  have been added, but the IC is already an extreme huge (for back then) 24 pin device. Not really worth it for something a standard 74 series 4 input chip can do.

---

### In Detail

> If I wanted to build a CPU with the typical flags Zero, Negative and oVerflow,

Seems like you already answered that question: One only needs a zero flag if one want's to a very specific CPU, one that is

1. working with flags (*2) and
2. features a zero flag (*3).

Neither assumption is true for all CPUs (*4).

> I have the unconfirmed feeling that I could use /G and /P and /F3 to emulate N and V

Kinda. IIRC - F3 equals N while (F3 and G) would give V (*3). Again combinations either direct available (like F3) or done by a simple gate. No need for P.

> but I don't see how I can get a Z flag bit without adding the usual 4 or 5-input NOR gate.

Which is exactly what everyone would have done.

> What did real world '181 CPUs do to get a Z flag? The A=B open-collector bit that comes out on pin 14 is active when F0-F3 are all one. So it seems like in active low mode this would make sense.

Equal, like signed by the chip, is not the same as Zero. It's meant for when the ALU is used in comperator mode - or handy with counting loops (*1).

Comparison mode is done setting it to subtract (A minus B) with carry set. Doing so makes  *A=B* together with Cn+4 reflecting *greater-then*, *equal* or *lesser-then* as described in the data sheet.

[image: Datasheet excerpt about use as comperator]

> Was the 74'181 really intended to be used in active low mode then?

It was meant to work in either. It's one of the most basic 74 series devices, a 7425, isn't it?

> It seems so strange!

Not at all. All mentioned in the data sheet.

---

*1 - Well, it reports, as noted, all ones. Beside comparison this could be quite useful as end detection for counters. Like byte counters in a transfer or compare where the limit is encoded as N-1.

In fact, of having only zero flag in counting loops (instead of a '-1' flag), is a well known issue of bugs in 6502 programs :))

*2 - One alternative (of several) to flags is a condition code. A more abstract and thus better to handle way to cover meta results of operation. Several great CPUs go that way, not at least IBM's /360.

*3 - Although this may as well depend on the way the CPU to be build defines flags.

*4 - It seems as if you had a very specific CPU and behaviour in mind when writing this. Behaviour that is not universal but design specific.

Comment: "One alternative to flags is a condition code.", Another alternative is testing (some bits of) the accumulator directly, like on the PDP-8 or Z22. The latter two computers do not have anything like a condition code or condition flags.

Comment: @OmarL yes, exactly. Another one would be no flags at all, but test instructions operating directly on the data to be questioned - usually implemented as test-and-jump (or skip) instructions. A very appealing idea, delivering a clear distinction between operations and testing. Just less great (early) real world implementation

Comment: What you describe is exactly what the PIC14 does, still a popular embedded platform today. It, along with the PDP-8 I already mentioned, could easily be implemented using 74181. But it would obviously not provide the conditional logic.

Comment: @OmarL Which is the whole point of the '181. It's an integration of the core components for a generic ALU (at the time) but not a finished product for a certain CPU design (which may as well be the source of Gunthers confusion, as he seems to try to see look at it to find a finished CPU specific implementation).