# Real applications for the "weird" functions of the 74181 ALU?

Tags: alu, 74ls181

Out of the popular but closed question [74'181 ALU why would anyone (have) use(d) these wild functions?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/74181-alu-why-would-anyone-have-used-these-wild-functions) I break off another part.

We know why those many logic function exist. I am not listing them again. You see it in the closed question. About half of the functions could be deemed useful, perhaps one more than half. So no need to bring up `A and (not B)` or `(not A) and B` again, masking operations, yes.

My question is: have any of the remaining "weird" functions been found useful? In what practical applications? I am especially interested in fast division and multiplication operations, perhaps MD5 hashing or others where something like `A plus (not AB)` or strange things like that might be just the thing to use. A fast right-shift would also be nice to construct without too much external circuitry.

Here is a list of the weird ones, ranked by most weird first.

- The weirdest ones are mixing logical with addition.
- The second weird ones are logical with carry
- The least weird ones are only logical (odd numbered in the full list below)

**Ranked by weirdness (weirdest first):**

1. ?? (A or B) plus (A and not B)
2. ?? (A or not B) plus (A and B), whoa!!!! whosoever can use this should get a prize
3. ?? A plus (A and not B), woah!
4. ?? (A or not B) plus A
5. ?? (A or B) plus A
6. ?? A plus (A and B)
7. ?? A or not B with carry?
8. ?? A or B with carry!
9. ?? (A and B) - 1, with carry
10. ?? (A and B) - 1
11. ?? not A or B
12. ?? not A xor not B
13. ?? A or not B
14. ?? not A or not B, that's a strange one
15. ?? A nand B, sure, a universal gate, but in an ALU?

Again, remember please, my question isn't "why do these exist" but what are actual uses someone might have found for them?

**Here is the complete list**, in the ordinal number - 1 is the bits of S3, S2, S1, S0, M from MSB to LSB. Just for perspective.

1. OK not A (regardless of B)
2. OK A (regardless of B), but mind the carry or else it's A-1, also OK
3. ?? not A or not B, that's a strange one
4. ?? A or B with carry!
5. OK not A and B, masking to clear all bits of A from B
6. ?? A or not B
7. OK all bits off
8. OK minus 1, all bits on
9. ?? A nand B, sure, a universal gate, but in an ALU?
10. ?? A plus (A and not B), woah!
11. OK not B (regardless of A), symmetric to 1st
12. ?? (A or B) plus (A and not B)
13. OK A xor B
14. OK A minus B, with carry L, test 7 - 2 = 5 the output carry is H, that seems so weird! Do we have to think of carry being active low?
15. OK A and not B, masking to clear bits of B from A
16. ?? (A and B) - 1
17. ?? not A or B
18. ?? A plus (A and B)
19. ?? not A xor not B
20. OK A plus B, but with carry H, if L you get A plus B + 1, so how can you do an add with carry? Or does this mean carry is actually active low? That would fit with the subtraction weirdness?
21. OK B (regardless of A and carry)
22. ?? (A or not B) plus (A and B), whoa!!!! whosoever can use this should get a prize
23. OK A and B
24. ?? (A and B) - 1, with carry
25. OK all bits on
26. OK A plus A (a left shift)
27. ?? A or not B
28. ?? (A or B) plus A
29. OK A or B
30. ?? (A or not B) plus A
31. OK A (regardless of B and carry)
32. OK A minus 1 (if carry is H)

Comment: Could you list the ones you consider to be weird?  Because, hypothetically, if I know of a use for some function, I probably don't think of it as weird.  And are you asking about the logical ops, arithmetic ops, or both?

Comment: Unless you wire the input shifted to the '181, it cannot shift right. But then you don't need it, anyway.

Comment: This does sound quite like an attempt to reopen the [question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/74181-alu-why-would-anyone-have-used-these-wild-functions) by tweaking it a tiny bit. Doesn't it? Beside of course that asking 'has anyone ever used a function x (out of a list) is more of a generic math question then related to computing and even less about retro computing.

Comment: How is "real applications for..." any different from "why would anyone have used...?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow if you haven't noticed, that other question is also mine and it was shut down. None of the answers were on point either.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow It might have been shut down for a good reason, so reopening it isn't exactly good sportsmanship (Not to add that answers might be quite to the point  especially if they don't hit your expectation)

Comment: @Raffzahn I detest such comment. It is completely ridiculous that I am being referred to my own question as if I wasn't aware of it. And this "it may have been" and you attacking my "sportsmanship" is outrageous, frankly. The reason given was that it asked several things at once. So I split it up. BUT the question got 6 upvotes in 24 hours, so it wasn't exactly irrelevant. And this is also why I did not edit it. Why are YOU a rule stickler? SE will self destruct because of rule sticklery instead of simply following in the interest of the subject matter.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow It might be a helpful if you take a step back and a deep breath here before carrying on with unnecessary attacks. Doing so you might have noticed that I didn't vote to close it, but spend quite some time to answer it. You may not like it, but it answers the points opened. It also did turn out rather "popular" (15 votes) - if one confuses votes for usefulness with popularity. But more important here: Editing is the process to improve questions to be reopened. Reposting is not. Complaining about rules to cooperate as well not.

Comment: The bottom line is that this shows the utter ridiculousness of SE culture. And for that I will leave it as it is. A cycle of two questions closed where one "reason" for closing is that it's a duplicate when the supposed duplicate is closed. It's idiotic and I know what's going on on SE, so I just leave it at that.